# Pattern recognition with double vectors

Tags: c++

I have a set of vectors which contain the same amount of entries. I have been googling for a while but i haven't found anything useful:

Is there a way to detect a pattern in these numbers?

The vectors look like this:

{840.2, 842.1,....,}
{840.3, 843.1,....,}
....

Comment: What do you mean a *pattern* ?

Comment: What kind of a pattern are you looking for? Something more of a Mensa puzzle or a general trend? Where does this data come from?

Comment: I don't think there's any chance of a useful answer unless either you explain what sort of pattern you're looking for, or someone happens to guess correctly. The former seems like a better bet. So: What sort of pattern are you looking for?

Comment: If you want to measure how closely the sequences resemble each other, then "correlation" would be a good word to google. If you mean something else, then please explain in more detail.

Comment: I'm sry if i didn't express my problem correct.The thing is i want see if the difference between the entries follows a pattern or a trend. These are peaks from a laser spectrum and i would like to take a "fingerprint" to see is i can identify a laser by its peaks. In other words if i have a certain vector the program should be able to tell me if this meets pattern 1 or 2, ... or whatever pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze your data, I suggest writing a program that puts the data into a Comma Separated Values formatted file, then input the file into a spreadsheet.  Spreadsheets already have great functions for analyzing data.

A good project would be to use (implement) a neural network for analyzing the data.  Search the Web for "Neural Network C++".

Comment: I already thought about the neural Network and found some pretty interesting things about it. The basic principle is clear to me, but I have no clue where to start and how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, I think you'll be interested in [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation).

The basic idea is that you have two vectors (one of length *m* and one of length *n*, where *n* is usually much smaller than *m*) and you create a third vector (of length *m* - *n*) whose values represent how well the smaller vector matches a portion of the larger at particular points.

The basic algorithm is something like:

```
for i = 0 to m - n
    output[i] = 0
    for j = 0 to n
        output[i] = output[i] + (v0[i + j] * v1[j])^2
```

The index of the maximum value in the output vector is where the smaller input vector best matches the larger.

This naive implementation is quite slow, but in the [Properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Properties) section of the above link, we see that we can use FFTs to calculate the cross-correlation much faster in general.

Comment: The thing in this algorithm is, that my vector are exactly the same size, so this wouldn't run at all. But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use metrics like the [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)  in order to determine how similar two vectors are.  If all of the vectors follow a similar trend, then their cosine similarities should also be similar.

Comment: Alright I just implemented to cosine similarity. I think it's not really precise enough. I only get results of 1 or really close to 1 (eg. 0.999994), but thanks for the idea.